# My Demon turtle

Tags: behavior

I have a 100 gal tank I had 4 small turtles and 1 turtle that was a little bigger than the 4 small ones 1 gold fish that was large and some other fish. The one larger turtle ate the head off of 1 small turtle. And ate all of the other turtles and ate half of the gold fish. How can I stop this turtle

Comment: What type of turtles? Behavior like this is often exacerbated when you mix species.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can put other animals in the tank with this turtle and expect him to not eat them. Turtles are wild animals, and you shouldn't expect them to feel compassion for smaller animals, even of the same species. If an animal thinks something might be food, you're going to have a hard time convincing them otherwise, and from what you tell in the question, the turtle has determined that the smaller turtles and goldfish are food.